# How to extract/parse HTML using Microdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microdata

I am pretty new to Microdata.

I have a HTML string with Microdata. I am trying to figure out if it's possible to extract the required information dynamically using Microdata with JS or jQuery. Has anyone done this before?

Example HTML string: I am trying to get the 'content' corresponding to itemprop 'ratingValue'  for item prop-name 'Blendmagic'

```
<html>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="name">Blendmagic</span>
        <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
        <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
            Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
        </div>
    </div>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="name">testMagic</span>
        <span itemprop="price">$10.95</span>
        <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
            <img src="four-stars.jpg" />
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
            Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: you should use `document.getItems()` in firefox, maybe a polyfill elsewhere. otherwise, you'll be looking at a bunch of yucky attrib-based code...

Comment: @dandavis Not so simple to compose; though doable. The native browser methods can return results; though often composers of semantic `html` include several different versions . g--gle has sch-ma , which has its own format ; vcard ; hcard ; microformats ; data- attributes - and microdata could all be included in a semantic web page . Additionally , authors can define their own "vocabulary" ; the "sch-ma" vocabulary is an example . Some authors may compose pages differently simply based on how g--gle parses page - not necessarily on how page will be parsed by others.

Comment: i'm surprised there's not a library for this exact task already. maybe i'll write one. yeah, there's 4-5 formats, but that's only 4-5 formats to "parse"...

Comment: i started, but i got distracted and now i have to go, but maybe it can help get you going: https://jsfiddle.net/j6zsyjzr/

Comment: Couldn’t you just use any of the various JS/jQuery Microdata parsers? If you just need a recommendation of a suitable one, you could ask on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try beginning at the root `itemscope` node , filter  descendant elements having `itemprop` attributes; return object `result` containing array `items` holding `Microdata` `item`s.

This solution is based on the algorithm found at [Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html)

> 7 Converting HTML to other formats
>
> 7.1 JSON
>
> Given a list of nodes nodes in a Document, a user agent must run the
>   following algorithm to extract the microdata from those nodes into a
>   JSON form:
>
> Let result be an empty object.
>
> Let items be an empty array.
>
> For each node in nodes, check if the element is a top-level microdata
>   item, and if it is then get the object for that element and add it to
>   items.
>
> Add an entry to result called "items" whose value is the array items.
>
> Return the result of serializing result to JSON in the shortest
>   possible way (meaning no whitespace between tokens, no unnecessary
>   zero digits in numbers, and only using Unicode escapes in strings for
>   characters that do not have a dedicated escape sequence), and with a
>   lowercase "e" used, when appropriate, in the representation of any
>   numbers. [JSON]
>
> This algorithm returns an object with a single property that is an
>   array, instead of just returning an array, so that it is possible to
>   extend the algorithm in the future if necessary.
>
> When the user agent is to get the object for an item item, optionally
>   with a list of elements memory, it must run the following substeps:
>
> Let result be an empty object.
>
> If no memory was passed to the algorithm, let memory be an empty list.
>
> Add item to memory.
>
> If the item has any item types, add an entry to result called "type"
>   whose value is an array listing the item types of item, in the order
>   they were specified on the itemtype attribute.
>
> If the item has a global identifier, add an entry to result called
>   "id" whose value is the global identifier of item.
>
> Let properties be an empty object.
>
> For each element element that has one or more property names and is
>   one of the properties of the item item, in the order those elements
>   are given by the algorithm that returns the properties of an item, run
>   the following substeps:
>
> Let value be the property value of element.
>
> If value is an item, then: If value is in memory, then let value be
>   the string "ERROR". Otherwise, get the object for value, passing a
>   copy of memory, and then replace value with the object returned from
>   those steps.
>
> For each name name in element's property names, run the following
>   substeps:
>
> If there is no entry named name in properties, then add an entry named
>   name to properties whose value is an empty array.
>
> Append value to the entry named name in properties.
>
> Add an entry to result called "properties" whose value is the object
>   properties.
>
> Return result.

```js
var result = {};
var items = [];
document.querySelectorAll("[itemscope]")
  .forEach(function(el, i) {
    var item = {
      "type": [el.getAttribute("itemtype")],
      "properties": {}
    };
    var props = el.querySelectorAll("[itemprop]");
    props.forEach(function(prop) {
      item.properties[prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [
        prop.content || prop.textContent || prop.src
      ];
      if (prop.matches("[itemscope]") && prop.matches("[itemprop]")) {
        var _item = {
          "type": [prop.getAttribute("itemtype")],
          "properties": {}
        };
        prop.querySelectorAll("[itemprop]")
          .forEach(function(_prop) {
            _item.properties[_prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [
              _prop.content || _prop.textContent || _prop.src
            ];
          });
        item.properties[prop.getAttribute("itemprop")] = [_item];
      }
    });
    items.push(item)
  })

result.items = items;

console.log(result);

document.body
  .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "<pre>");

var props = ["Blendmagic", "ratingValue"];

// get the 'content' corresponding to itemprop 'ratingValue' 
// for item prop-name 'Blendmagic'
var data = result.items.map(function(value, key) {
  if (value.properties.name && value.properties.name[0] === props[0]) {
    var prop = value.properties.reviews[0].properties;
    var res = {},
      _props = {};
    _props[props[1]] = prop[props[1]];
    res[props[0]] = _props
    return res
  };
})[0];

console.log(data);
document.querySelector("pre").insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + "<pre>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">Blendmagic</span>
    <span itemprop="price">$19.95</span>
    <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <img data-src="four-stars.jpg" />
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="name">testMagic</span>
    <span itemprop="price">$10.95</span>
    <div itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
      <img data-src="four-stars.jpg" />
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />Based on <span itemprop="ratingCount">25</span> user ratings
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

See also [Recursion and loops of Microdata items](https://readable-email.org/list/whatwg/topic/recursion-and-loops-of-microdata-items)

Comment: @dandavis Interesting . At jQuery source `.attr()` appear to fallback to `.prop()` when `attribute` `undefined` ?

Comment: prop uses the dom binding to prop, attr get's the prop attrib. if the browser doesn't provide the "content" dom binding (which only works on meta), then prop() won't work, but attr() always will.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, `meta` element utilized at `html` ; frequently where microdata included.

Comment: This solution includes nested itemscope itemprops in the parent scope *and* in the nested scope. That doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zmq7d03/3/)

```
$("span[itemprop='name']").each(function(e) {
    if ($(arguments[1]).text() == 'Blendmagic') {
        alert($($("meta[itemprop='ratingValue']")[e]).attr('content'));       
    }    
});
```