# How to semantically mark up a pre-headline ‘kicker’ in HTML?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Many news websites have a little "pre-headline" before every article headline (as shown in screenshots from Guardian and FT, below). Sometimes this is a link to the article's category/tag/column, other times it's just a piece of static microcopy to give context to the headline. Journalists often call it a 'kicker'.

Currently I'm just using a `div.kicker` to mark this up, but is there a more appropriate semantic element to use?

```
<header>
    <div class="kicker">Science</div>
    <h3>New frontier as astronomers witness neutron stars colliding</h2>
</header>
```

[image: Guardian screenshot]
[image: FT screenshot]

Comment: *is there a more appropriate semantic element to use?* Define appropriate? Appropriate to who and why?

Comment: @Liam – ‘Appropriate’ in terms of [semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) – that is, as semantically precise as possible. For example, in semantic HTML, `<em>` is more appropriate than `<i>` to represent emphasis, because it's more semantically precise.

Comment: That depends on what's reading it. What google decides is the most semantic is going to be totally different to a bing web spider or a screen reader for a blind user. The term semantic markup is mostly unhelpful. It's not a well defined concept.

Comment: The concept of a [semantic web was pretty much abandoned in 2013](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/). So there are no standards for what your asking

Comment: You're confusing [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) with [semantic HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML). These are completely different things. If you don't understand the area I'm talking about, please consider removing your downvote and close-vote, as they unfairly bury my question.

Comment: Sure. It's my fault no one answered your question...Definitely not the questions fault. Look I'm trying to point out flaws in your question to help you get an answer. If you don't want to listen and instead simply wish argue with me then fine but I fail to see how that helps you. good luck

Comment: But you haven't defined what you would deem appropriate. There is no standard for appropriateness (regardless of what you deems semantic web whatever is)? That's why this is opinion based. What you deem appropriate I may not. What Google deems appropriate  Bing might not. There is no W3C standard on this so there is no defacto answer, therefore it is (as it stands) unanswerable.

Comment: Maybe https://ux.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate for this. But I'm not convinced you'll get much more than what I've already said here

Comment: _"The concept of a semantic web was pretty much abandoned in 2013."_ Which facts made you draw that conclusion? Microdata, microformats, JSON-LD are still being deployed, and the Structured Data Testing Tool, formerly Rich Snippets Testing Tool, is still live and operational.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There really isn't a more appropriate element and what you've got already is fine.

Note that semantic HTML is not a goal in itself, but a means to achieve *media independence*. So what you should be considering is how the content will be experienced when presented or consumed by other media than a graphical UI.

For example, think about screen reader users. One of the things that they commonly do is to interrupt the text that's being read and skip on to the next heading element. If they do that in this instance, they will miss hearing the kicker. Does that matter? That's a judgement call for you. In the examples you give above, my opinion would be that it doesn't; that there's enough information in the heading alone for them to be able to decide whether to read the story or not. If on the other hand, your view is that the kicker contains critical information for them to be able to make that decision, you might want to put the kicker inside the heading element.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `h?` tag with the number being one of lower significance then the one on the title element.

So if you are using `h3` for the title i would use `h4` or `h5`.
(*if you are using subtitles, the kicker should be even lower*)

---

That is also how facebook marks its articles (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/cover/)

Comment: Doesn't this break the regular flow of the headings? You could end up with an h5 (kicker), followed by an h3 (title) and h4 (subtitle). It would be valid HTML but, from a semantic/accessible point of view, wouldn't this be inconsistent?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I believe that semantically it would be fine, although in terms of how accessibility devices would understand this, you raise a valid point. The code in the question seems the most valid then, using a `header` and nesting a `div` or `span` with a `h3`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<article>`

> 4.3.2 The [article](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element%20element) element
>
> The article element [represents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#represents) a complete, or self-contained,
>   composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in
>   principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in
>   syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper
>   article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget
>   or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

and `<section>` elements

> 4.3.3 The [section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) element
>
> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.

for markup and include structured data within the HTML markup describing the content of `<article>` and `<section>` element; for example using [HTML Microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata), which can be parsed to [`JSON`](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#json), see [How to extract/parse HTML using Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201345/how-to-extract-parse-html-using-microdata/).

Comment: I don't think you read the question. I'm asking about the pre-headline kicker, not the whole article card.

Comment: @callum Yes, read the question. Each of the images at OP, if HTML, can be an `<article>` element including optional embedded metadata about that snippet; if the requirement is consistent semantics throughout the entire document. Perhaps the question is actually not about including complete semantic markup and machine readable data within the HTML document describing the content therein?

Comment: @callum What is your goal for adjusting the HTML markup? Are you adjusting the markup just to adjust it? Or are you adjusting the markup for consumers of HTML, or for that matter, any other document transmitted on the web?